# Google Spreadsheet When converting the GoogleFinance currency returned value only from the first line

Tags: spreadsheet

In Google Spreadsheet the column "B" three rows with prices in $, but when converting the currency returned value only from the first line, please tell me where the error?

[image]

```
=QUERY(importXML("https://www.globalpetrolprices.com/Azerbaijan/", "//*[@id='graphPageLeft']/table[1]//tr"), 
"Select Col4 
 label Col4 '' 
  format Col4 '0.00'") 
   * GOOGLEFINANCE("currency:USDEUR")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was advised this solution:

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(importXML("https://www.globalpetrolprices.com/Azerbaijan/", "//*[@id='graphPageLeft']/table[1]//tr"), 4, 4), "Select Col4 label Col4 ''") * GOOGLEFINANCE("currency:USDEUR"),"€ 0.00"))
```